# Используем HTTP Геокодер, зарегистрировали apikey,

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

мой аккаунт ikskron@yandex.ru
запрос следующий:

```
https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?lang=ru_RU&apikey=xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxx- 
xxxx-7615e7c736f6&geocode=Спб%20Невский%20104
```

Помогите разобраться, почему при указании верного кода, система сообщает, что он не верный:

```
<error>
<statusCode>403</statusCode>
<error>Forbidden</error>
<message>Invalid key</message>
</error>
```

Comment: если зарегистрировали минуту назад, и ждете что уже будет работать, то подождите еще 14

Comment: больше часа прошло, ошибка осталась

Comment: мб больше времени требуется нынче. я вчера тоже для карт ключ получил, первое время не работали, а  сегодня утром норм уже было все. Хотя до этого таких проблем не наблюдалось, почти сразу ключики работали.

Comment: Заработало. Всем спасибо.)